# Why do we say “un seul M” and not “une seule M” even though M is a “consonne”?

Tags: grammaire, histoire, genre, alphabet

When spelling names, for example “Bram”, to make clear that there's only one *M* at the end I hear French people say “Avec un seul *M* à la fin”. But “*M* est une consonne” therefore “un nom feminin”. So why is that?

Comment: I don't understand why the gender of the word "consonne" would be related to the gender of individual letters. If you say "le lait est une boisson" it doesn't suggest that "lait" should be feminine even though "boisson" is.

Comment: @Moyli Le lait est un breuvage, un liquide.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The gender of letters is masculine nowadays but that wasn't always the case for some consonants, including *m*.

[TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/f)

> **Rem.** Les noms désignant les lettres *f, h, l, m, n, r, s* sont traditionnellement féminins (il s'agit des noms en *-e : effe, ache, elle, emme, enne, erre, esse*, d'apr. la transcr. orth. ds *Lar.* 20e). On commence par attribuer le genre masc. à la désignation de la lettre par la valeur : *un fe, effe* restant lui fém. (Ac. jusque Ac. 1878, Littré, DG). Ac. 1932 admet pour *effe* les 2 genres; v. aussi Rob. La 1<sup>re</sup> attribution du genre masc. à *effe* ds *Nouv. Lar. ill.* 1897.

I have no answer to the *why* question though, beyond the fact in the past, feminine consonants names weren't starting with themselves but with an *E* and that now the gender is consistent for all letters.

Letters were likely already masculine in ancient French but feminine in Latin.

There is no common usage among Romance languages:

- In Italian, letters can be used either in masculine or feminine gender.
- In Spanish and Catalan, letters are feminine.
- In Portuguese and Romanian letters are masculine.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe it is adding a character (un caractère) which is masculine ?

Comment: @AzirisMorora or *un signe*, but *lettre* is really what they are always called.

Answer (score 4):

COMPLÉMENT DE RÉPONSE

The following considérations are meant to make more precise the apparently no so uncommon notion that the gender of a generic term dictates that of the nouns that are used as those in the kind named. The conclusion is that there is  no such general principle but that there is nevertheless ground to think there is a limited principle, and that would tend to explain the intuitive notion that it could be general one.

It's a mostly valid statement to say there is no principle telling that a generic term should give its gender to the nouns that name something under the category it describes;

- "combustible" is  masculine  but "essence" is feminine and "mazout" is masculine;
- "médicament" and "antibiotique" are masculine but "pénicilline" is feminine as are also numerous other medicines;
- "fonction" is feminine but the mathematical functions "cosinus", "sinus" and "logarithme"  are masculine whereas "tangente" and "exponentielle" are feminine;
- "couleur" is feminine but all common colour names are masculine;
- "voile (de bateau)" is feminine but the names of specific sails are sometimes feminine (misaine, brigantine, … ), sometimes masculine (foc, grand hunier, …)
- "épice" is feminine but "poivre", "cumin" and "curry" are masculine whereas "cannelle" and "muscade" are feminine;
- "légume" (une carotte, un oignon, une tomate, un céleri rave, une pomme de terre,…)
- "fleur"  (un dahlia, une rose, un myosotis, une pensée, un nénuphar, …)
- "insecte" (une mouche, un cafard, une abeille, un moustique, une guêpe, …)
  …

*exceptions*

- "arbre"; at least all the nouns of common trees are masculine, as is the generic term; (un chêne, un hêtre, un pommier, un pêcher, un platane, un saule, un amandier, un cerisier, …)

---

What we can say is that there is a tendency for that principle to be true 
**1** when there is a close connection between the generic term and what it names, that connection being close in that way that there is little or no evolution in the number of elements named and that they form a compact whole,
**2** or  when the name is the proprietary name of a product or the proper name of a product.

*examples of "**1***"
 figures de notes de musique (ronde, blanche, noire, croche, etc.), chiffres, jours de la semaine, siècles, temps grammaticaux, éléments de la table périodique, vitamines (la majorité des noms de vitamine sont féminins)

*examples of "**2***"
 vin, voiture

*exceptions to "**1***"
couleurs (all colour names are masculine whereas "couleur" is feminine), lettres de l'alphabet (all masculine), notes de musique (the names are masculine : un do, un ré, etc.)

Comment: The *notes de musique* should be listed as exceptions to "1" in your answer. *Une note* but *un do, un ré, un mi, etc.*

Comment: @jlliagre I should add those, which are not the intended "notes" (une ronde, une blanche, une noire, une croche, etc.), as I thought only of the notes as "figures de note".

Answer (score 3):

Selon cet article :

http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-le-nom-des-lettres-une-h-un-h-l-h-le-h-112484780.html

> On a coutume aujourd'hui de donner le genre masculin au nom des
> lettres. Un A, un B, un L, un X, etc. **Il n'en a pas toujours été
> ainsi**. Certaines lettres, dont le nom commence par une voyelle,
> étaient des substantifs féminins.
>
> On peut dire encore le féminin pour F, L, M, N, R, S, H (prononcer une
> effe, une elle, une emme, une enne, une erre, une esse, une ache) mais
> cet usage tombe en désuétude.
>
> On peut faire ou ne pas faire d'élision, l'h ou le h, l's ou le s. On
> trouve, dans la littérature, une I, une H muette ou aspirée, une L
> mouillée, un I grec, une X (rare) etc. Cf. Grevisse
>
> Le Trésor donne ache pour l'orthographe du nom de la lettre H ; il
> cite une comptine recueillie dans Comptines de langue française,
> Paris, Seghers, 1970, à retrouver aussi dans  Le catalogue de la
> chanson folklorique française
>
> A, B, C, D, La vieille Babbé ;
>
> E, F, G, H, Elle a pris une hache ;
>
> I, J, K, L, Elle s'est coupé les ailes ;
>
> M, N, O, P, Elle s'est coupé le pied ;
>
> Q, R, S, T, Elle ne s'est pas découragée ;
>
> U, V, X, Y, Z, Elle a eu des pieds aux ailes
>
> « Le nom de la lettre est inscrit, [...] dans la rime : E, F, G, H.
> Elle a pris une hache. »
>
> Le Littré donne le nom esse pour la lettre s.
>
> L'Académie 8ème édition 1932-1935 donne F masculin et féminin : Un
> grand F, une petite f.
>
> ......................................................
>
> Selon La Grammaire générale et raisonnée de 1660, L'épellation des
> consonnes se fait ainsi : be, ke ou se, de, fe, ge, he, je, ke le, me
> ne pe, ke, re, se, te ve, we, kse, ze. —be, prononcer [bə], etc.—
>
> Inconvénient : le C, le K et le Q se prononcent tous les trois ke !
>
> On note que cette épellation n'est jamais entrée dans l'usage.
>
> ......................................................
>
> Dans le Dictionnaire de l'Académie 4ème édition 1762 : on note que les
> lettres F, L, N, S, X, autrefois substantifs féminins sont devenues
> substantifs masculin et se prononcent fe, le, ne, se :
>
> F substantif féminin suivant l'ancienne appellation qui prononçoit
> Effe; & masculin suivant l'appellation moderne qui prononce Fe.
>
> L substantif masculin suivant l'appellation nouvelle, qui prononce Le;
> & féminin, suivant l'appellation ancienne, qui prononçoit Elle. N
> suivant l'appellation ancienne, qui prononçoit Enne; & masculin,
> suivant l'appellation moderne, qui prononce Ne.
>
> S substantif féminin suivant l'ancienne appellation qui prononçoit
> Esse; & masculin, suivant l'appellation moderne qui prononce Se.
>
> X substantif masculin - Lettre consonne, qui est la vingt-troisième
> lettre de l'Alphabet François. Suivant l'ancienne appellation, on la
> nommoit ics, & suivant la nouvelle, on l'appelle xe.

Answer (score 0):

Surely because "M" or any letter doesn't have a gender, and in French grammar, masculine wins if doubt (yeah old rules).

Comment: We say *une Mercedes, une Fiat, une Volvo* when it's a car and *un Mercedes, un Iveco, un Volvo* when it's a truck.

Comment: une voiture, un camion ... here for example, "X" could be anything, not just a letter, but also a mathematic constant, anything.

Comment: It can be argued letters probably already had a gender before being used as mathematics constant or anything else.